# JustMock helpers in another class return null in test

Tags: c#, justmock

I moved the most frequently created mocks into extensions and helper classes to be able to reuse them in several tests. I was very surprised when it turned out that they are appently context dependent and don't work when sitting elsewhere.

This code demonstrates the issue:

```
void Main()
{
    // Does not get the mock user.
    var db = MockFactory.MockUserDatabase();        
    db.GetUsersAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().Dump(); // <-- null

    // This works and gets the mock user.
    var mock = Mock.Create<IUserDatabase>();
    mock
        .Arrange(x => x.GetUsersAsync())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new[] { new User { Name = "John" } }));

    mock.GetUsersAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().Dump(); // <-- mock user

}

static class MockFactory
{
    public static IUserDatabase MockUserDatabase()
    {
        var mock = Mock.Create<IUserDatabase>();

        mock
            .Arrange(x => x.GetUsersAsync())
            .ReturnsTask(new[] { new User { Name = "John" } });

        return mock;
    }
}

public static class JustMockHelpers
{
    public static IAssertable ReturnsTask<TReturn>(this IAssertable assertable, TReturn value)
    {
        return assertable.Returns(Task.FromResult<TReturn>(value));
    }
}

public interface IUserDatabase
{
    Task<User[]> GetUsersAsync();
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can make the `JustMock` code encapsulated in other classes work too?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are using a Static MockFactory and it works when you use it directly not statically. Why Would use a static class if you are still initiating the test data each time and each time you recreate the mock? Either try to have a base testing class with this method and call it base.YourInitialiseMethod() or something like TestFixtures. If you look at documentation of JustMock they always do create inside each test case individually.

Comment: About that _If you look at documentation of JustMock they always do create inside each test case individually._ - yeah, I've noticed that but documentations usually do this for simplicity. I hadn't thought that this would be for a reason. Why am I doing this like that... mhmmm that's the only way I know ;-]

Comment: My guess is the Mock itself is static and it is doing something inside of it when creating that prevents it from using inside another static, what exactly I am really left to guess, unless looking at the source code. I would really prefer something like xUnit does here to re-create each time inside constructor before each test case and then you just arrange inside your test.

Comment: The arrangement part is what I wanted to move to a helper in the first place. I'm disappointed at JustMock :-( I was hoping there would be some context manipulation API hidden in some _secret_ namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a trick. You can pull it to the same `static` context with a `Func`. `ReturnsTask` still won't cooperate but at least the general arrangement does.

```
static class MockFactory
{
    public static Func<IUserDatabase> MockUserDatabase
    {
        get
        {
            return () =>
            {
                var mock = Mock.Create<IUserDatabase>();

                mock
                    .Arrange(x => x.GetUsersAsync())
                    .Returns(new[] { new User { Name = "John" } }.ToTask());

                return mock;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I turned the other extension around and made it:

```
public static Task<T> ToTask<T>(this T obj) => Task.FromResult(obj);
```

Then I just call:

```
.Returns(new[] { new User { Name = "John" } }.ToTask())
```